# can not invoke webmethod to save handsonTable

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I want to  save handsontable data into json file,I have a javas cript method to get all data from handsontable as

```
 $('button[name=save]').click(function () {
            var str = handsontable.getData();
            var value = JSON.stringify(str);
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/getData",
                data: { 'data': value }, 
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.result == 'ok') {
                        alert('Data saved');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Save error');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);

                }
            });
        });
```

But I am not able to invoke WebService.asmx/getData(List data) .

```
 public string getData(List<String> data)
{
    return "";
}
```

What I need to pass in data:??...Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
            data: { 'data': str  }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
```

With the `contentType` setting you are telling the server that you are sending JSON data, but you aren't. `{ 'data': str  }` is not a JSON string; it is a standard Javascript object literal. You are invoking the default jQuery behaviour for creating HTTP requests. This means you're sending a regular HTTP request, something like:

```
?data=thedata
```

To send actual JSON data, you need to call `JSON.stringify`:

```
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'data': str  }), 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have change the function    data: { 'data': JSON.stringify(str) }, and the web method  is "public string getData(List<String> data)" ,Do I need to change method argument datatype?

Comment: @Ankit No idea, sorry. I know jQuery, but nothing about ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

you must write before methode

```
[WebMethod]
```

and change parameters of method from List to string

then you can split it